# Efficient MySQL query method for multiple joins

Tags: mysql, performance, select, join

I am asking this question in the hope there is a more efficient (faster) way to pull and insert data in the the tables I am working with.

The basic structure of the data table is

```
    ID Doc_ID    Field     Value
     1    10    Title       abc
     2    10    Abstract    xyz
     3    10    Author      Bob
     4    11    Publisher   Bookworms
     5    11    Title       zzz
     6    11    Abstract    bbb
     7    12    Title       aaa
     8    12    Sale        No
```

In other words the data tables are row based, each row contain a document id and the corresponding field value. Not all documents have the same number of fields defined. Indeed books may differ radically from magazines.

The data table is 10,000,000 rows typically a document has 100 fields associated with it.

So the performance problem I am finding is pulling a report with reference to 50+ different fields, for example if I have a query list in an order_table the query could be like

```
    select ord.number as 'Order ID', d1.value as 'Title', d2.value as 'Author' .......
    from order_table ord
    LEFT JOIN data_table as d1 on d1.Doc_ID=ord.Doc_ID and d1.Field='Title'
    LEFT JOIN data_table as d2 on d2.Doc_ID=ord.Doc_ID and d2.Field='Author'
    ........
    LEFT JOIN data_table as d50 on d50.Doc_ID=ord.Doc_ID and d50.Field='Qty'
```

Using LEFT JOINS as there is no guarantee that the field is defined for that document.

Given there may be some WHERE parameters to limit the list to items (in stock for example or below a price) it is a slow query. Indexes don't really much.

Without being able to change the data model, what is the best way to pull volumes of information out?

Comment: This is called a "pivot". MySQL doesn't have it built in like some other databases do, but if you search SO for "mysql pivot" you'll find better solutions, as it's a common question.

Comment: This explains things well, will see if I can follow it through and get around performance issues